# mechanism that make a string empty after std::move() it

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have some confusion about how a `std::move()` really empty something.

I write some code:

```
int main()
{
    string str1("this is a string");
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<str1.empty()<<std::endl;
    string str2(std::move(str1));
    cout<<"str1: "<<str1.empty()<<endl;
    cout<<"str2: "<<str2.empty()<<endl;
}
```

The output is:

**false**

**true**  //this mean the original string is emptied

**false**

Why is the original string emptied every time?
I have read some meterial about the move semantics,including the original proposal of it([this one](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm)), which said:

> The difference between a copy and a move is that a copy leaves the source unchanged. A move on the other hand leaves the source in a state defined differently for each type. The state of the source may be unchanged, or it **may be radically different**. The only requirement is that the object remain in a self consistent state (all internal invariants are still intact). From a client code point of view, choosing move instead of copy means that you don't care what happens to the state of the source.

So,according to this words, the original content of the **str1** above should be some kind of **undefined**. But why is that every time it have been `move()`, it is emptied?  (Actually I have test this behavior on both `std::string` and `std::vector` but the result is the same.)

To learn more, I define my own string class to test, as bellow:

```
class mstring
{
private:
    char *arr;
    unsigned size;
public:
    mstring():arr(nullptr),size(0){}
    mstring(char *init):size(50)
    {
        arr = new char[size]();
        strncpy(arr,init,size);
        while(arr[size-1] != '\0') //simply copy 
        {
            char *tmp = arr;
            arr = new char[size+=50]();
            strncpy(arr,tmp,50);
            delete tmp;
            strncpy(arr-50,init+(size-50),50);
        }
    }

    bool empty(){ return size==0;}

}
```

Doing the same thing:

```
int main()
{
    mstring str("a new string");
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<str.empty()<<std::endl;
    mstring anotherStr(std::move(str));
    std::cout<<"Original: "<<str.empty()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Another: "<<anotherStr.empty()<<std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

**false**

**Original: flase**  //mean that the original string is still there

**Another: false**

Even I add a move constructor like this:

```
    mstring(mstring&& rvalRef)
    {
        *this = rvalRef;
    }
```

The result is still the same.
My question is: why is the `std::string` get emptied but my self-defined isn't?

Comment: "A move on the other hand leaves the source in a state defined differently for each type. "  - It's actually not even that. The object is left in an _unspecified_ state.

Answer (score 5):

Because that's how the `std::string` move constructor is implemented.  It takes ownership of the old string's contents (i.e. the dynamically-allocated `char` array), leaving the old string with nothing.

Your `mstring` class, on the other hand, doesn't actually implement move semantics.  It has a move constructor, but all it does is copy the string using `operator=`.  A better implementation would be:

```
mstring(mstring&& rvalRef): arr(rvalRef.arr), size(rvalRef.size)
{
  rvalRef.arr = nullptr;
  rvalRef.size = 0;
}
```

This transfers the contents to the new string and leaves the old one in the same state that the default constructor would have created it.  This avoids the need to allocate another array and copy the old one into it; instead, the existing array just gets a new owner.

Comment: You should stress that that is precisely what 1) move constructor is meant for and 2) what `std::basic_string` (and other standard library containers) does.

Comment: This ignores the fact of the small-string optimization used by common implementations

Answer (score 0):

> So,according to this words, the original content of the `str1` above should be some kind of *undefined*.

There is absolutely *nothing* about what the state *should* be. The specification says what the state *could* be: *anything* defined enough that it can be destroyed or assigned new value.

Empty qualifies as anything, so the state can be empty.

It also makes most sense in this case. A string is, essentially, something like

```
class string {
    char *_M_data;
    size_t _M_size;
    size_t _M_alloc;
public:
    ...
}
```

where the _M_data is allocated with `new` and must be deleted with `delete` (this is customizable with the allocator parameter, but the default allocator does just that).

Now if you don't care about the state of the source, the fastest thing that can be done is to assign the buffer to the destination and replace the buffer with `nullptr` in the source (so it does not get deleted twice). A string with no buffer is empty.